# Count values of an Excel column in different ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, counting

I want to count number of values in different ranges in an Excel column.

**Example 1:**
Imagine I have some data in 40 rows, each one happened in different time of day. Like the below image:

[image: excel rows with time specified]

now I want to count number of row repeated in different ranges, for example, count number of rows that have time between 12:00 to 18:00, again count 18:00 to 00:00, and more to 11:59 (next 12:00)

| Time range | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00 to 6:00 | ? |
| 06:00 to 12:00 | ? |
| 12:00 to 18:00 | ? |
| 18:00 to 23:59 | ? |

Finally I have a table with 4 rows that shows how many row I have in those ranges and I can create a chart by that.

**Example 2:**
Count people based on age range. result would be like this:

| Age range | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 12 to 18 | 3 |
| 18 to 25 | 5 |
| 25 to 35 | 4 |
| 35 to 45 | 1 |
| 45 to 60 | 2 |

P.S:
I used **countif** with logical AND, but it didn't work. like this: `=COUNTIFS(C:C,"AND(<00:00, >2:00)")`

Comment: You count ages but you use a column with time-values? Can you explain a bit more how you derived your desired results?

Comment: sorry for confusing, the second one (age) was an another example of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to sort this out. You are showing desired results that do not belong to the give formula you have shown. Please do not confuse your readers.

Comment: @JvdV ok sure and done!

Comment: No you have not. The table does not match the formula you mentioned. This is utterly confusing.

Comment: @JvdV I used an example result for Example 2. Do I HAVE to do the same for example 1?

Comment: Again; you are asking about a count of rows between two different times. Why would you include a table showing age ranges? A good question includes good sample data, with reproduce-able output. It's highly confusing. My advise: include the desired output of your actual question, not that of something unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more correct use of COUNTIFS (which is different from COUNTIF), would be :

```
'Counts values strictly between 00:00 and 2:00
=COUNTIFS(C:C,">00:00",C:C,"<2:00")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: here is the same solution and seems it should be correct but I don't know why it doesn't work for me :( https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/date-and-time/count-times-in-a-specific-range

Comment: @SaeedSepehr, what is your output when you try `VALUE(C2)`. Are your values actual  time-values and not dates (integers with decimals) formatted to only show times?

Comment: @JvdV its 0.628472222

Comment: Then the answer given here is absolutely correct.

Comment: Are your upper and lower bounds correctly defined ? In you example (i.e. `=COUNTIFS(C:C,"AND(<00:00, >2:00)")`), it counted times inferior to 00:00 and superior to 2:00, which is a null set and returns 0. Alternatively, depending from where you are you might want to try `=COUNTIFS(C:C;">00:00";C:C;"<2:00") `.

Comment: @ThomasC. thanks but none of them works! :( I might attach my excel file

Comment: @SaeedSepehr does the function work for ages ? 
`=COUNTIFS(your_range,">12",your_range,"<18") `

Comment: @ThomasC. yes it works, but for time not.

Comment: @SaeedSepehr strange ! Make sure the cells display the same time format that the COUNTIFS uses. If it doesnt work, i am afraid i dont know what to do. EDIT : using Pivot Tables and groups might also suit your needs (cf :https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-pivottable-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725)

Comment: The problem solved. there was one cell including wrong data. that was 0:45 instead 00:45 
thanks for your help guys. thanks so much